# Srcoll iframe log text from bottom

Tags: html

Currently, I have

```html
<iframe src="logs.txt" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>
```

But it reads the text from the top, and I have to scroll to get to the bottom.
I'd like to reverse this and start from the bottom. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to the bottom of the page like this:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

however, you have two pages in this situation: the main page inside which there is an `iframe` and the page displayed by the `iframe`. You will need to run the code above inside the `iframe`. If the domain is the same, then you can do it like this:

```
<iframe src="logs.txt" width="100%" height="300" onload="document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);">
```